# Trigger+procedure issue

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, procedure, database-trigger

As the title says, I have an issue with the trigger + procedure.

What I'm trying to do it's a procedure + trigger that creates an email with the name and surnames only if when I'm trying to insert a student data w/o an email.

Basically where am stuck is, the code makes the fusion of name and surname and creates the email, but how do I place it before it inserts inside the table?

Best regards,
Engineer
Here's the code I have made:

```
use alumnesTriggers;

drop procedure if exists ex2;
delimiter //
create procedure ex2 (in nom varchar(50), in cognom1 varchar(50),
                        in cognom2 varchar(50), in domini varchar(50), out email varchar(50))
begin
    set email := concat(nom,cognom1,cognom2,'@',domini,'.com');
    #set @email := email;

    #UPDATE alumnesEmail as ae SET ae.email = @email WHERE nom = @nom;
end //
delimiter ;

drop trigger if exists ex2_2_trigger;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER ex2_2_trigger before insert on alumnesEmail for each row begin
    set @mail := new.email;
    #if @mail := null or @mail='' then
        set @id := new.id;
        set @nom := new.nom;
        set @cognom1 := new.cognom1;
        set @cognom2 := new.cognom2;

        call ex2(@nom,@cognom1,@cognom2,'gmail',@email);
        UPDATE alumnesEmail SET new.email = @email;

    #end if;
END $$
DELIMITER ;

INSERT INTO `alumnesEmail` (`id`, `nom`, `cognom1`, `cognom2`, `email`) 
VALUES (80, 'a', 'a', 'a',null);

select * from alumnesEmail where id = 80;
select @email;
select * from alumnesEmail ;
```

Comment: Solved, I had to add "set new.email = @email; "

Comment: How do you create new students ? If you are using a stored procedure then I would keep all the related code in one place. What about students who leave or change their legal name ? Will table  `alumnesEmail` be kept up to date ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but how do I place it before it inserts inside the table?

In a `before` trigger, you just set `new.email`  to the target value. This modifies the value that is *about to* be written to the database.

Also, the procedure seems superfluous here.

The following code should do just what you want:

```
delimiter $$
create trigger ex2_2_trigger 
before insert on alumnesemail
for each row 
begin
    if new.email is null or new.email = '' then
        set new.email = concat(new.nom, new.cognom1, new.cognom2, '@gmail.com');
    end if;
end $$
delimiter ;
```